# PowerMockito spy calling real method gets NullPointerException

Tags: java, unit-testing, mockito, powermockito

When calling real method `service.listObjectA("abc")` from spy class, I got null pointer exception, which points to the original class's ArrayList initiation line `List<ObjectASummary> objAList = new ArrayList<>()`.

I debugged this in IDE and took this [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/g3HQV.png) of stack trace details.
It says `Method threw 'java.lang.NullPointerException' exception. Cannot evaluate net.bytebuddy.description.type.TypeDescription$ForLoadedType.toString()`

I was also told to paste the stack trace, so here it is.

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at com.myorg.myproject.service.ObjectAService.listObjectA(ObjectAService.java:181)
    at com.myorg.myproject.test.testcases.api.unit.ObjectAServiceTest.testListObjectA(ObjectAServiceTest.java:95)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:62)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:498)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.TestMethod.invoke(TestMethod.java:66)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:326)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie$2.run(MethodRoadie.java:86)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(MethodRoadie.java:94)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:310)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTestInSuper(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:131)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.access$100(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:59)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner$TestExecutorStatement.evaluate(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:147)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.evaluateStatement(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:107)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit47MethodRunner.executeTest(PowerMockJUnit47RunnerDelegateImpl.java:82)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$PowerMockJUnit44MethodRunner.runBeforesThenTestThenAfters(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:298)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.runTest(MethodRoadie.java:84)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.MethodRoadie.run(MethodRoadie.java:49)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.invokeTestMethod(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:218)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.runMethods(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:160)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl$1.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:134)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runUnprotected(ClassRoadie.java:34)
    at org.junit.internal.runners.ClassRoadie.runProtected(ClassRoadie.java:44)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.internal.impl.PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.run(PowerMockJUnit44RunnerDelegateImpl.java:136)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.run(JUnit4TestSuiteChunkerImpl.java:117)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.common.internal.impl.AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.run(AbstractCommonPowerMockRunner.java:57)
    at org.powermock.modules.junit4.PowerMockRunner.run(PowerMockRunner.java:59)
    at org.junit.runner.JUnitCore.run(JUnitCore.java:157)
    at com.intellij.junit4.JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.startRunnerWithArgs(JUnit4IdeaTestRunner.java:68)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.IdeaTestRunner$Repeater.startRunnerWithArgs(IdeaTestRunner.java:47)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.prepareStreamsAndStart(JUnitStarter.java:242)
    at com.intellij.rt.execution.junit.JUnitStarter.main(JUnitStarter.java:70)
```

**ObjectAService.java Line 181:** `List<ObjectASummary> objAList = new ArrayList<>();`

Here is the class to test:

```
public class ObjectAService {

    public ObjectAService(ObjectADataProvider dataProvider, WorkRequestService workRequestService, ObjectBServiceInterface objBService, ObjectCFactory objCFactory, SWConfig swConfig) {
        //constructor
    }

    @Override
    public List<ObjectASummary> listObjectA(String s) {           

        List<ObjectASummary> objAList = new ArrayList<>();//NullPointerException thrown from this ArrayList initiation line

        /*
        Code to query backend for the list and process them.
        The back end query client is mocked and behaviors are stubbed in the test.
        */

        return objAList;
    }
}
```

Here is the test:

```
@RunWith(PowerMockRunner.class)
@PrepareForTest({ObjectAService.class, RealmIdFactory.class})
@PowerMockIgnore({ "javax.net.ssl.*", "javax.security.*" })
public class ObjectATest {

    private SystemClient swClient;
    private ManagedInstanceService service;

    public ObjectATest() {

        service = PowerMockito.spy(new ObjectAService(null, null, null, null, new SWConfig()));
        swClient = PowerMockito.mock(SystemClient.class);
    }

    @Test
    public void testListObjectA() throws Exception {

        List<ClientSystem> systems = new ArrayList(listSize);
        for(int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            systems.add(new ClientSystem());
        }
        PowerMockito.doReturn(swClient).when(service,"getSystemClient");
        PowerMockito.doReturn("xxx.yyy.zzz").when(service,"getObjectAOcid", anyString());
        PowerMockito.doReturn(ObjectADetails.Status.Normal).when(service, "getClientSystemOsaStatus", any(SystemClient.class), anyInt());

        PowerMockito.when(swClient.listSystems()).thenReturn(systems);

        List<ObjectASummary> list = service.listObjectA("abc");
        assertNotNull(list);
    }
}
```

Comment: Please, add stacktrace to your question. It's not clear from screenshot - what's going on. By the way, it's not a good idea to post images on external systems and add links to them to your question because the images will be deleted after some time and your question will become useless for other developers, searching for a solution for a similar problem.

Comment: @Vusa thanks for looking at the question. Stacktrace is added, though I don't find much information out of it.. Also, I atempted to post image directly in the question but I don't have enough reputation to do so. The screenshot was uploaded to stack overflow not some external system though.

Comment: `ObjectAService.java:181` - what code located at this line?

Comment: @Vusal, it is the initiation of an array list, which you can find in the first code snippet.List<ObjectASummary> objAList = new ArrayList<>();//NullPointerException thrown from this ArrayList initiation line

Comment: Thank you for provided info. Taking into account that you are passing a lot of `null` values to the constructor of your `ObjectAService` and that your `listObjectA` interacts with DB (as you stated in the question) - the NPE here is inevitable. But if indeed the NPE happens at `ArrayList` creation line - then you probably found some bug in PowerMock.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why you're using PowerMock but there is no use here to me.
Usage of PowerMock is very specific and there is usually a problem of conception behind.

I recommand you to simply use Mockito alone and see if the problem is still there.

If the problem vanish, then report it to dev team.